# How to set defaults for each newly created Linux user?

Tags: linux

On a server we have discovered that we need to add the FTP passive command in every users .netrc file when we create a new user.

Can this and other defaults (in .something files) be automatically created when a new user is created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On almost all Linux distributions the standard user creation tools will copy the contents of `/etc/skel` into the users newly created home directory.  At least for standard users and not **system** users.

Some distributions like Debian/Ubuntu, which have the adduser command all provide a method where you can additional scripts to be called for post-processing after the new user is created.

- useradd http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd
- adduser (Debian/Ubuntu/& other derived) http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/adduser.8.html

Answer (score 2):

@least Under redhat derivatives,  useradd copies all the files found under /etc/skel to the new user's home.

Answer (score 2):

Put default skeleton files in `/etc/skel` directory. Those files will be copied to new user home directory, just remember to use `-m` parameter in `useradd` command.